# Allows Multiple in zapier cli application

Tags: zapier-cli

I'm building a Zapier app using CLI, there is an option like "Allows Multiple" in Zapier UI but I didn't find anything like allowsMultiple in CLI documentation. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CLI, the property is `list`, which should be set to `true` on your `inputField`.

There's docs here: https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/schema/docs/build/schema.md#properties-15